# What's the difference between Lucene's KeywordAnalyzer and Hibernate Search's PassThroughAnalyzer?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

Are they the same thing? It seems like PassThroughAnalyzer is redundant.
Plus Hibernate Search even has the option to explicitly disable analysis via annotation attribute:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
```

Seems like yet another way to achieve exactly the same result. What's the point?

Answer (score 1):

Similar indeed, but what's the issue? From a Hibernate Search perspective it is only relevant that you say Analyze.NO. What exactly happens internally is not relevant, right? Whatis your problem or question?